# How does Virtual Machine Monitor trap Syscalls?

Tags: x86, arm, virtual-machine, virtualization

As I understand it, in order to correctly emulate syscalls issued by user programs running in guest OS, VMM must trap all syscalls to itself before jumping to guest OS’s interrupt handler.

Assuming a hosted VM, since guest OS is running in user mode in host OS, how does VMM trap syscalls in guest OS instead of allowing syscalls fallthrough VMM to host OS? If this is achieved by binary translation, how are syscall instructions translated in VMM for x86 or ARM?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong, at least for modern VMMs running on x86. Syscalls made by user code in the guest are handled by the guest operating system. The VMM isn’t involved. (The VMM may get involved when the guest OS accesses a virtual device.) The guest OS doesn’t run in user mode.

Comment: You're talking about hardware-assisted virtualization, right?  ARM has that too (I think), and the whole point is that the guest can truly run in kernel mode, not user, and only trap to the VMM for hardware access, not for guest-user <-> guest_kernel transitions.

Comment: @prl According to this note https://web.stanford.edu/~ouster/cgi-bin/cs140-winter12/lecture.php?topic=vmm, “Kernel calls in guest OS” section near the middle, syscalls first trap into VMM before control returns to guest OS. In particular, second line says “Traps always go to VMM”, so my question is how VMM achieves this? Did you mean this is not how VMM works in modern x86 virtualization?

Comment: @PeterCordes Hardware-assisted Virtualization is designed for bare-metal VMs I believe (please correct me if I am wrong)? In this question, I am primarily interested in hosted VMs which run on top of a host OS. How does guest OS run in kernel mode in hosted VM (since it’s just a user mode program on host OS)?

Comment: That document was out of date even when it was written. Hardware support for virtualization has been available in x86 since 2005 (Pentium 4), except in some Atom processors.

Comment: Hardware support for virtualization is used for hosted VMs as well. No VMM can be written as just a user mode program; they all require a kernel module. (A user mode program can use pure simulation of the full architecture, but I would call that a simulator, not a VMM.)

Comment: A pure user-space program that a guest OS can run under is called an emulator ([like QEMU without KVM support](https://serverfault.com/questions/208693/difference-between-kvm-and-qemu)).  That *is* a type of virtual machine, but @prl meant it's not a hypervisor. or virtual machine *monitor*.  And not the kind of VM that people normally mean when they say VM.  Hosted VMMs kind of turn the host kernel into a hypervisor for the guest machines, and include some code that runs in the host kernel.  (e.g. to run under a Linux host they always include a kernel module.)

Comment: @prl Thanks for the clarification guys! Do you have pointers for how modern VMM works in depth by any chance? Appreciate your help.

Comment: @PeterCordes Appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest searching for design documentation on KVM, the open source VMM that is integrated into the Linux kernel.